# Syntastic does not perform syntax checks with new plugin

Tags: vim, neovim, syntastic

I just added a new plugin (vim-loves-dafny) to my `~/.config/nvim/init.vim` file. I've got the necessary executables installed.

```
% which dafny
/usr/local/bin//dafny
```

But `/dafny` doesn't find anything in `:help syntastic-checkers`, and when I edit a Dafny file, I don't get any sort of highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot and just needed to enable the checker.

Fixed by adding `let g:syntastic_dafny_checkers = ['dafny']` to my config.